# Globalize3: "Mysql2::Error: Unknown database" when running the 'rake db:seed' task

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, globalize3

I am using rails-3.2.2, i18n-0.6.0 and globalize3-0.2.0 ruby-gems. I [installed](http://railscasts.com/episodes/338-globalize3) and correctly run Globalized for a my class named `Article`. However, when I run the `rake db:seed` task in the Terminal window I get the following error:

```
$ rake db:seed
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Unknown database 'article_translations': SHOW TABLES IN article_translations LIKE 'title'
```

In my `<ROOT_APP>/config/seed.rb` file I have:

```
Article.find_or_create_by_title(
  :title => 'Title example',
  ...
)
```

In my `<ROOT_APP>/app/models/article.rb` file I have:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  translates :title, :fallbacks_for_empty_translations => true

  ...
end
```

*How can I solve the error?*

More details at https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3/pull/123.

---

*Note*: I think the problem is related to the `find_or_create_by_title` method called in the `<ROOT_APP>/config/seed.rb` (in fact, if I use the `find` method instead of `find_or_create_by_title` I do not get the rake error explained above). If it is true, *what I can do to keep my `seed.rb` file clear since I will need some hack* (for example, like that shown below) *to solve the problem?*

```
# The below code has the same effect as the 'find_or_create_by_title' method.
Article.create(:title, 'Title example updated!') unless Article.exists?(:title => 'Title example')
```

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you failed to run rake db:create / rake db:migrate first

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue with Globalize3  https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3/issues/78